# USB transmitter

Tags: usb, wifi

Does anyone know if there exist some device marked as "X" on this image? I could not find anything. 
Transfer range should be at least 10m. 
Also "Some Device" is just piece of hardware, so there can't be installed anything on it.

**UPDATE**:
[image]
Updated the image so it is more clear. Need something like wireless USB. So if I connect "Some Device" to "X" it will be recognized by Notebook. 
I am not sure, but maybe it is possible to programme the "Y" as a virtual USB. I mean to catch the wifi data and transfer it to virtual USB, so that the application on Notebook can communicate with "Some Device".

Comment: For a small constrained device maybe [this](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00AKXOVG6/ref=pd_rhf_eeolp_s_vtp_ses_clicks_0_9?ie=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B00AKXOVG6&pd_rd_r=53Q20TK5CSVYY8JZ16BF&pd_rd_w=Upfzw&pd_rd_wg=s8L9G&pf_rd_i=desktop-rhf&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_p=05d75987-58ed-4d36-bbfa-515cd87e4ee3&pf_rd_r=53Q20TK5CSVYY8JZ16BF&pf_rd_s=desktop-rhf&pf_rd_t=40701&psc=1&refRID=53Q20TK5CSVYY8JZ16BF), otherwise your diagram is functionally equivalent to a [NAS server exposed over a router](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822107985R&cm_re=nas_storage-_-22-107-985R-_-Product).

Comment: Some routers support NAS storage like linksys that allow for you to plug in a normal mass storage device to the router and have the router expose the drive to the network.

Comment: I updated the question. I think what you suggested will not work. But anyway thanks for the tip.

Comment: There are more of these than I would have guessed actually... the search term you’re looking for is ‘wireless usb extender’